# startNetworkServer.bat (DERBY) на jdk 1.8.0_45 (Oracle) не работает

Tags: java

При попытке запустить сервер DERBY, который идет в комплекте с JDK 1.8.0_45 от Oracle не происходит ровным счетом НИЧЕГО. И непонятно в чем проблема. Никакого лога, никаких записей в консоли - он просто не запускается.

Comment: Пожалуйста, больше информации - какая ОС, как вы его запускаете.

Comment: ОС - Windows 7 x64, но речь здесь идет о версии JDK для x86. Запускал я его по разному: двойным кликом по .bat-файлу, вызовом указанного .bat-файла из консоли. Результат в обоих случаях одинаковый

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собственный анализ, не без помощи его величества fernflower, выявил, что ошибка в банальном NullPointerException:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.derby.iapi.tools.i18n.LocalizedResource.getTextMessage(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.localizeMessage(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.localizeMessage(Unknown Source)
        at custom.NetworkServerControl1.installSecurityManager(NetworkServerControl1.java:216)
        at custom.NetworkServerControl1.main(NetworkServerControl1.java:81)
```

Последние две строки несколько искажены моим вмешательством, но они нас не интересуют. Второй сверху метод localizeMessage выглядит так:

```
private String localizeMessage(String var1, LocalizedResource var2, String[] var3) {
  String[] var4 = null;
  if(var3 != null) {
    ...
  }
  return var2.getTextMessage(var1, var4);
}
```

Здесь "падение" происходит в последней строке, т.к. `var3` на входе `null`. В JDK версии 1.7.0_80 этот же метод выглядел так:

```
private String localizeMessage(String var1, LocalizedResource var2, String[] var3) {
  String var4 = null;
  if(var3 != null) {
    ...
  } else {
    var4 = var2.getTextMessage(var1);
  }
  return var4;
}
```

В обоих случаях `getTextMessage` это один и тот же метод с сигнатурой:

```
String getTextMessage(String var1, Object... var2)
```

В старом коде он вызывался без второго параметра, а в новом вторым параметром явно пробрасывается `null`. Разумеется он не готов к такому повороту событий и вылетает `NullPointerException` при попытке пройти цикл по массиву.

В данной ситуации, очевидно, выход один: пользоваться старыми версиями JDK в ожидании исправления в новых версиях.